# Memory Leak using knockout.js 2.3.0 and jquery mobile 1.3.1

Tags: knockout.js, memory-leaks

We are using knockout 2.3.0 and jquery mobile 1.3.1. We use the $.mobile.changePage api to transition from one screen to another and we bind the ko ViewModel to the corresponding dom element in pagebeforeshow and clean up the bindings of the previous screen using the removeNode in pageshow. Below is the code for the same:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
            var prevId = ui.prevPage.attr('id');
            console.log('Clean node = ' + prevId);
            if (prevId && $('#' + prevId)){
                if($('#' + prevId)[0]){
                    console.log("$('#' + prevId) =  " + $('#' + prevId)[0]);
                    ko.removeNode($('#' + prevId)[0]);
                }
            }
        });

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
            var Screen1VM = function() {
            };
            var Screen2VM = function() {
            };
            var path = event.target.id;
            if(path == 'Screen1'){
                var vmObj = new Screen1VM();
                ko.applyBindings(vmObj, document.getElementById('Screen1'));
            }else if(path == 'Screen2'){
                var vmObj = new Screen2VM();
                ko.applyBindings(vmObj, document.getElementById('Screen2'));
            } 
        });
    });
```

Taking the Heap Snapshot after explicitly doing a Garbage Collection on Chrome Dev Tools and filtering for objets Screen1VM and Screen2VM, we see that the references for these are held by a every growing knockout Object array. The Object count is always equal to the number of times we visit the screen and this never comes down. Please let me know if there is anything wrong that is done here.